# Has Saudi Arabia expelled ambassadors before over human rights comments (from their government)?

Tags: international-relations, human-rights, canada, saudi-arabia

In the [latest news](https://edition.cnn.com/2018/08/06/middleeast/saudi-arabia-canada-intl/index.html) on Saudi Arabia, they have expelled the Canadian ambassador (and recalled their own ambassador to Canada) in reaction to human rights comments from Canada, or more precisely demands from Canda over the realease of specific persons.

Has Saudi Arabia done anything like this in the past? I'm aware of their extended row with Qatar, but that is/was [more complex](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-40476821) than just some comments.

Comment: On its face the move appears to be rather extraordinary. In 2016 Saudi Arabia did halt diplomatic relations with Iran [Saudi Arabia cuts diplomatic ties with Iran](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2016/01/saudi-arabia-severs-diplomatic-relations-iran-160103202137679.html), though the cause was not comments made on the Internet. The Saudi Arabian government does pay close attention to media, particularly concerning reports about the war in Yemen.

Comment: Has any government before demand release of the specific prisoners? If not, what is the point of asking this question?

Comment: One past example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_of_a_Princess?wprov=sfla1

Comment: @mikado: actually that seems good enough for an answer, even if wasn't a government position directly on human rights they were reacting to. Asking for media censorship in a foreign country for a human-rights-focused dramatization and then expelling the ambassador seems close enough.